# Running chef-client throws 404 "Object Not Found" (Net::HTTPServerException)

Tags: chef-infra

I have just started working with Chef, and I am quite new to to the DevOps field.
I installed Chef Server, it worked fine, then I started playing with Knife a little bit and added two clients - my MacBook (OS X) and an Ubuntu 10.04 server that I don't manage myself, so I had to ask a sysadmin to install chef-client to this machine. I created a test cookbook and added it to the run-lists of each client. However, when I tried to run chef-client on both of them, on my Mac OS X machine everything worked fine, while the Ubuntu 10.04 run was throwing an error:

```
$ sudo chef-client

[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:32:26 +0200] INFO: Starting Chef Run (Version 0.9.18)  
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:32:27 +0200] ERROR: Running exception handlers  
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:32:27 +0200] ERROR: Exception handlers complete  
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2101:in `error!': 404 "Object Not Found" (Net::HTTPServerException)
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:234:in `api_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:285:in `retriable_rest_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:215:in `api_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:226:in `api_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:335:in `follow_redirect'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:226:in `api_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:285:in `retriable_rest_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:215:in `api_request'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/rest.rb:111:in `get_rest'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/client.rb:252:in `sync_cookbooks'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/client.rb:165:in `run'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/application/client.rb:222:in `run_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/application/client.rb:212:in `loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/application/client.rb:212:in `run_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/chef/application.rb:62:in `run'
from /usr/bin/chef-client:26
```

The error looks quite general, so it doesn't help too much to figure out what is the cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: make sure you have installed the last version of Chef Client.

---

Long answer:

The first thing to do in order to get more details is enabling a better logging in the client.rb file. Usually you do that by adding to /etc/chef/client.rb the following line:

```
log_level :debug
```

That already showed me what resource the client was trying to access:

```
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:46:10 +0200] DEBUG: Sending HTTP Request via GET to  
    chef.xxxxxx.xxxxx.com:443/nodes/node-apache1.xxxxxx.com/cookbooks  
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:46:10 +0200] ERROR: Running exception handlers  
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:46:10 +0200] ERROR: Exception handlers complete  
[Wed, 17 Apr 2013 16:46:10 +0200] DEBUG: Re-raising exception:   
Net::HTTPServerException - 404 "Object Not Found"
```

It was a non-existent resource because the sysadmin had installed the client from Opscode's Ubuntu repo and this one wasn't the last version of it, and it was incompatible with Chef Server 11. I asked him to **install the latest version of the client** from [the Chef Client install page on Opscode.com](http://www.opscode.com/chef/install/)

As you can see there, you can either download the desired package or just run

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | sudo bash
```

for the latest version.

Running chef-client works all right now.

Answer (score 2):

PS: I am not sure this will help others or not but I managed to resolve this same issue in the following way.

If you ssh into the box and then run this command

> sudo chef-client --runlist "your_cookbook_name"

it will prompt the exact error. So you can take action according to the error.

BDW in my case, when I checked through above method. I found that I didn't create the `Environment` in https://manage.chef.io/.